# Angular/JS get two $event.target.value in one method

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to do a range from -> to search of postal codes. I have two input fields and a simple method. Is it possible to use a method with 2 arguments?
Here is my method:

```
 searchPostalCode(from:number, to:number):void{
    console.log('from:' + from);
    console.log('to:' + to);
  }
```

And my inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" placeholder="from" (input)=searchPostalCode($event.target.value)>
<input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" placeholder="to" (input)=searchPostalCode($event.target.value)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the most straightforward way would be to have two properties on the component and two methods updating those:

```
postalCodeFrom: number;
postalCodeTo: number;

updateFrom(value: number): void {
  this.postalCodeFrom = value;
  this.search();
}

updateTo(value: number): void {
  this.postalCodeTo = value;
  this.search();
}

search(): void {
  // Make better checks - this will fail on 0
  if (!this.postalCodeFrom || !this.postalCodeTo) {
    // run some logic?
    return;
  }

  // run the actual search.
}
```

Then have your inputs bound to that method:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" placeholder="from" (input)=updateFrom($event.target.value)>
<input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" placeholder="to" (input)=updateTo($event.target.value)>
```

Of course there are other ways (like using RxJS) but the above should be good enough for the start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use  form module and do something like this.

```
myForm: FormGroup;
from = '';
to = '';
```

inside ngOnInit:

```
 this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    from: [this.from],
    to: [this.to]
});

this.myForm.controls['from'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});

this.myForm.controls['to'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

and HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
   ...

  <input type="text" name="from" [(ngModel)]="from" formControlName="from" placeholder="from"/>


  <input type="text" name="to" [(ngModel)]="to" formControlName="to" placeholder="to"/>

   ...
</form>
```